# Getting objects in Autocomplete Field?

Tags: ajax, django-views, django-forms, fetch-api

Updated question and added templates.

I have a working autocomplete field that displays my users, to select them. I cannot get the name and filter it to get the id. See view below.

How do I use the name I get from the POST request to filter properly for the id of the user?

html

```
<input name="user" id="user" type="text" list='results' placeholder="Type Customer's name" class="form-control">
     <datalist id="results">
       {% for x in results %}
           <option value="{{x.first_name}}"></option>
       {% endfor %}
     </datalist>
```

view.py

```
def customer_note(request):
      if request.method =="POST":
            customer_form = CustomerForm(request.POST)
            if customer_form.is_valid():
                  get_id = customer_form.save(commit=False) # getting first and last name here to do something with it. The Input in my first post is in a Form. and CustomerForm is that form.
                  full_name = User.objects.filter( Q(id__icontains=get_id))
                  customer_form.instance.id =  full_name.id #This is where I am stuck.
 . . .
```

models.py

```
    class User(AbstractUser):
    """User can be Employee or Customer"""


class Business(models.Model):
    business = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Customer(models.Model):
    """ Customer-specific information """
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True )
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    cust_notes = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, 
    selected_cust = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True )


class Employee(models.Model):
    """ Employee-specific information """
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Exactly where do you use `commit=False`?

Comment: It also looks very "strange" to do this, because `first_name` is not unique, and therefore probably eventually can refer to multiple users.

Comment: can you [edit] the question with the view, template etc. you can leave out details that don't matter.